# Flex real type definition in scientific and engineering notation in c++

Tags: c++, notation

I'm defining a real type and I'm using strtod for the exponential way even though is untested and don't really know if it works but more imporantly I would like to know if there is any built in function like strtod for engineering notation and if there isn't, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtod` understands exponential notation. See, e.g., http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtod.html .

Answer (score 0):

How about `scanf()` with the `%g` or `%G` format specifier (depending on whether you use e or E in your numbers)?